# Why won't the HTML select form element $_POST multiple values in PHP?

Tags: php, forms, if-statement, post, drop-down-menu

```
if (isset($_POST['ids']) && $_POST['ids'] === 'ford') {
  echo "yah!!!";
  print_r($_POST);
  $filename = "ford.txt";

} elseif (isset($_POST['ids']) && $_POST['ids'] === 'toyota') {
  print_r($_POST);
} elseif (isset($_POST['landrover']) && $_POST['ids'] === 'landrover') {

} elseif (isset($_POST['algonquin']) && $_POST['ids'] === 'algonquin') {

} elseif (isset($_POST['errors']) && $_POST['ids'] === 'errors') {

}
```

testing to see if $_POST superglobal array is posting.  It is only posting one value 'ford'.  Not sure why none of the other values aren't posting.

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $filename; ?>" target="box" >
    <select name="ids">
      <option value="ford">Ford</option>
      <option value="toyota">Toyota</option>
      <option value="landrover">Land Rover</option>
      <option value="algonquin">Algonquin</option>
      <option value="errors">Errors</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="View File" />


  </form>
```

This is the form with all of the options and their values.  It has a variable $filename which links to a text file which is meant to be opened in a target box.  The if statement above is supposed to determine what file to open.

`<iframe src="" name="box" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>`
The iframe or target box the file is supposed to open in.

Comment: `$_POST['landrover']` will never be set.  That isn't how you access the values.  You can't hope to use values as keyed and get what you want.  The selected option will be accessible via `$_POST['ids']` ...no matter what the value is.

Comment: `action="<?php echo $filename; ?>"` => `action="ford.txt"` - Huh? I don't get this.

Comment: Your `form action` is going to a `text file` should be a `php file`

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to `POST` multiple values from your `<SELECT>`, you will need to make a few modifications.

Let's start with your form...

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="selections.php" target="box" >
    <select name="ids[]" multiple>
        <option value="ford">Ford</option>
        <option value="toyota">Toyota</option>
        <option value="landrover">Land Rover</option>
        <option value="algonquin">Algonquin</option>
        <option value="errors">Errors</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="View File" />
</form>
<iframe name="box" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

1. Your form will need to be received by a `.php` file, not a `.txt` file.  I'm not sure what you are trying to do with `$filename`.
2. If you want to allow multiple selected options on your form, make the name value an array like: `ids[]` and write `multiple` inside the `<select>`.
3. If you don't need the `submit` value on your POST receiving file, then you don't need to write a `name` attribute on `<input type="submit">`

---

On your submission receiving page (let's call it `selections.php`), the `$_POST array can look like the following:

If you selected `Ford`, then:

```
$_POST=array('ids'=>array('ford'),'submit'=>'View File');
```

If you selected `Toyota` and `Errors`, then:

```
$_POST=array('ids'=>array('toyota','errors'),'submit'=>'View File');
```

If no selections are made, then :

```
$_POST=array('submit'=>'View File');
```

To check this SUPERGLOBAL data, you can use the following:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo "No submission data";
}elseif($_POST['submit']=='View File'){
    echo "Invalid/Unexpected submit data";
}elseif(empty($_POST['ids'])){
    echo "No ids selected";
}else{
    $valid_ids=['ford','toyota','landrover','algonquin','errors'];
    $_POST['ids']=array_intersect($_POST['ids'],$valid_ids);  // validate
    foreach($_POST['ids'] as $id){
        // do whatever you like with $id , perhaps $filename=$id.".txt" or something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is presumably happening because you're not checking the $_POST['ids'] value in the following if conditions. I would wager that if you selected 'toyota' it would work.

This is what your code should look like

```
if (isset($_POST['ids']) && $_POST['ids'] === 'ford') {
  echo "yah!!!";
  print_r($_POST);
  $filename = "ford.txt";

} elseif (isset($_POST['ids']) && $_POST['ids'] === 'toyota') {
  print_r($_POST);
} elseif (isset($_POST['ids']) && $_POST['ids'] === 'landrover') {
  print_r($_POST);
} elseif (isset($_POST['ids']) && $_POST['ids'] === 'algonquin') {
  print_r($_POST);
} elseif (isset($_POST['ids']) && $_POST['ids'] === 'errors') {
  print_r($_POST);
}
```

Edit:
as mentioned above, it seems like you're implying that the form should go to ford.txt?